# Compare field on form to another field on the same form - Conditional Formatting

Tags: forms, ms-access, conditional-formatting

I would like to compare a field on my form to another field on the form using conditional formatting, specifically the two fields named dbo_Tape.B1YearBirth and dbo_Tape Capture.B1YearBirth.

I have tried setting the conditional format for the field **[dbo_Tape Capture].B1YearBirth** to:

|Field Value Is| |not equal to| [Forms]![Application_Form]![dbo_Tape Capture.B1YearBirth]

AND I have tried:

|Field Value Is| |not equal to| [dbo_Tape.B1YearBirth|

Could someone please explain to me how to compare the two fields on my form called dbo_Tape.B1YearBirth and dbo_Tape Capture.B1YearBirth.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `dbo_Tape.B1YearBirth` the actual control name (not control source)? If yes, the second version should work.

Comment: Yes, it is the actual control name. However, it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control name cannot have a ., space or invalid character. If this is corrected, then the conditional formatting will work. Below is an example:

**WORNG:**   |Field Value Is| |not equal to| [dbo_Tape.B1YearBirth|
**CORRECT:** |Field Value Is| |not equal to| [dbo_Tape**_**B1YearBirth|